# Парсинг библиотека BeautifulSoup: как получить элементы <a> с заданным атрибутом

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть ссылки вида:

```
<a chapter="1" href="/url1/">1</a>
<a chapter="2" href="/url2/">2</a>
<a chapter="3" href="/url3/">3</a>

<a name="n1" href="/url1/">1</a>
<a name="n2" href="/url2/">2</a>
```

Как можно получить href'ы только ссылок с атрибутом "chapter"?

Comment: Использовать xpath или css-селектор с указанием наличия тега. Или в лоб: получить список тегов a, отфильтровать те, у которых есть атрибут `chapter`

Comment: Как отфильтровать-то? Не могу к такому тегу обратиться. Код в студию

Comment: Получение списка тегов: `a_list = root.select('a')`

Comment: Спасибо братец.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = '''
    <a chapter="1" href="/url1/">1</a>
    <a chapter="2" href="/url2/">2</a>
    <a chapter="3" href="/url3/">3</a>
    <a name="n1" href="/url1/">1</a>
    <a name="n2" href="/url2/">2</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', chapter=True):
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный и немного более лаконичный способ - использовать [CSS селекторы](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) - на данный момент `BeautifulSoup` поддерживает *ограниченный набор селекторов* - но для большинства повседневных задач хватает:

```
for a in soup.select('a[chapter]'):
    print(a)  # или print(a.get_text()) чтобы распечатать тексты ссылок
```